# How do you enable wobbly windows in ubuntu 11.04 without using compiz?

Tags: compiz, windows, appearance, effects

I'm curious if there's a way to enable the more fun UI features in Ubuntu 11.04 that were available in previous versions.  The effects I'm most curious about is the wobbly windows and the alt tab program switcher that looked like a rolodex.  Those things were delightful.  I've been reading about the compiz tool and since I'm a pretty noob user, I don't think I want to risk destroying my desktop for a chance to get these effects back.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible.. that's a compiz effect. And no Compiz will not make your PC explode.

Comment: I'm assuming by "Compiz tool", you mean CCSM and not Compiz itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently can enable this feature by installing **Ubuntu Tweak** and going under **Desktop > Compiz Settings > Enable wobbly windows**, no CCSM required. You can download an appropriate .deb for Ubuntu Tweak from [this Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+download) (I'd recommend getting the latest Natty .deb, which currently looks like `ubuntu-tweak_0.5.14-1~natty1_all.deb`).

*Note: I have not tried this solution myself; it may or may not mess Unity up, though I'd assume that if the option is available in 11.04's version of Ubuntu Tweak then it was at least lightly tested to work. I discovered this solution from a screenshot on [this blog post](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/5-useful-compiz-tweaks-for-ubuntu-1104.html).*

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have three options:

1. Find another WM that provides the desired effects. AFAIK, Compiz is the only one, but perhaps you'll discover something no one knows about.
2. Learn coding and write a WM that supports those effects.
3. Magic, many people believe it works.