# how can I enable wobbly windows without using CCSM

Tags: compiz

I am using ubuntu12.04 and unity.

Conpiz config settings manager makes my unity desktop carsh easily, so I wonder how to enable wobbly windows effect without using CCSM?

As I know, in the ubuntu 11.04, ubuntu tweak 0.5 provide some compiz settings,

[How do you enable wobbly windows in ubuntu 11.04 without using compiz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114982/how-do-you-enable-wobbly-windows-in-ubuntu-11-04-without-using-compiz)

but in the 12.04 and latest ubuntu tweak 0.7 doesn't have desktop tweak tool.

Answer (score 2):

Well I just did this thing and it worked for me.
Here's the way:

1. You must have `gconf-editor`, known as **Configuration Editor** to enable wobbly plugin without using CCSM.
2. Once you have it installed, browse to `/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/`.
   [image: gconf-editor]
3. Open **active_plugins**. And first, you have to remove **snap** plugin. It's to prevent crashing.
   [image: snap]
4. After that, you just have to add **wobbly** plugin, the one you wanted.
   [image: wobbly]
5. Enjoy.

Comment: Do the opposite to disable it. (Remove wobbly, and add snap.)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `compizconfig-settings-manager` as compiz effects are not natively in gnome 3.4 which unity in 12.04 is based off

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, I just do it anyway and if it crashes, restart and you might have it.
Just from my experience.

Comment: crash, that's the problem... that's why I don't like use CCSM ...

Comment: At least after you get everything set, you won't have to use it anymore. ccsm is just the settings manager, if it crashes when you open it, it won't do anything to the wobbly windows as long as you can get them set.