# Enable Wobbly Windows correctly

Tags: unity, 13.04, compiz

Whenever I want to enable the *Wobbly Windows* plugin in CCSM, it tells me the following:

```
Plugin "Snapping Windows" provides the feature "edgeresistance", which
is also provided by "Wobbly Windows".
```

I have the options to keep WW disabled or to enable WW and disable Snapping. When I do this my GUI gets unusable (decoration vanished, unity not working,...) until I delete all Compiz configuration files manually in TTY.

So how do I enable *Wobbly Windows* correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but I guess CCSM thinks that wobbly windows doesn't have a unity dependency and as a result it disables unity after enabling that effect. I have tried it myself and after a restart unity is gone: no launcher, no nothing. I would stay away from CCSM.

There is a way to get the wobbly windows effect without using CCSM: https://askubuntu.com/a/166772/292615

**EDIT**

Actually, the solution I pointed to is kind of long and I found an easier way to enable it without messing up unity.

1. Open *CCSM* and go to `Preferences > Plugin List` tab.
2. Uncheck `Automatic plugin sorting`.
3. On the left panel find `wobbly`. Select it and press the right arrow.
4. `wobbly` should have moved from the left to the right panel.
5. And the effect should now be working.